# Django TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <User: >

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-migrations

I've migrated my database and I got the error of **IntegrityError at /add/
NOT NULL constraint failed: base_notebook.user_id** when trying to add a note. I put the camps of null and blank but still have this error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1823, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'User'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\notepad\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\notepad\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 104, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 330, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 191, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 310, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 971, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 842, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2486, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1825, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <User: >.
```

Here is my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Notebook(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Notes(models.Model):
    notebook = models.ForeignKey(Notebook, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And here are my views:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def addNote(request):
    notebooks = Notebook.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST
        note = request.POST.get('content')

        if data['notebook'] != 'none':  # 'notebook' é o nome do meu input na minha template
            notebook = Notebook.objects.get(id=data['notebook'])
        elif data['notebook_new'] != '':  # 'notebook_new' é o nome do meu input na minha template
            notebook, created = Notebook.objects.get_or_create(name=data['notebook_new'])  
        else:                                                                      
            notebook = None

        Notes.objects.create(
            notebook=notebook,
            title=data['title_note'],
            content=note,
            user=request.user,
        )

        return redirect('home')

    context = {'notebooks': notebooks}
    return render(request, 'base/add_note.html', context)
```

I have already tried to delete by database using python manage.py flush but still didn´t work, and I can't migrate because this error

Comment: The error you're having is happening in migrations,  right? Could you show the migrations for that app?

Comment: I've already fixed it, I just wrote my database in a wrong way kkkkk, thanks!